# Export Photos in Catalina

Tags: photos, catalina

Is there a way to export photos from an album in Photos.app on my MacBook then to a folder in that order?

Since Catalina, I've not been able to do that even with titles and and the number box checked in export, but I have always been able to do that in previous OS X systems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how to export an album to a folder on your Mac, while preserving the order in which you had arranged them in the album? The steps below are for Monterey but will also work for Catalina, Big Sur etc.

Open the album in Photos on Mac and select all the photos. Click File > Export > Export N photos > in 'File Naming' section, change 'File Name' to Sequential > Click Export > click the 'New Folder' button at bottom left and input your album's name > click Export.

To export multiple (or all) albums and folders while maintaining the folder and album hierarchy, ordering, nesting structure etc., you could use the third-party app [Photos Takeout](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/photos-takeout/id1500714691?mt=12).